# Функция двойного копирования файла

Tags: c++

Есть ***функция***, которая на вход принимает путь до файла.

*Её цель*: Создать файл с таким же названием, но с окончанием `_double.txt`. Далее ***функция*** должна **2** раза скопировать **всё** содержимое из **1-ого файла** во **2-ой файл** соответственно.

*К примеру*: На вход подаём файл `text.txt` с содержимым `hello`. После выполнения ***функции***, должен создаться файл `text_double.txt` с содержимым `hello` (и на новой строчке ещё) `hello`;

```
void double_copy(string p) {
    string p2 = p;
    ifstream f1(p);
    for (int i = p.size(), c = 5; c != 0; --i, --c) {
        p2.erase(i);
    }
    p2 += "_double.txt";
    ofstream f2(p2);
    string str;
    while (getline(f1, str)) {
        f2 << str << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно было просто начать чтение файла сначала.

```
void double_copy(string p) {
    string p2 = p;
    ifstream f1(p);
    for (int i = p.size(), c = 5; c != 0; --i, --c) {
        p2.erase(i);
    }
    p2 += "_double.txt";
    ofstream f2(p2, ios::app);
    string str;
    while (getline(f1, str)) {
        f2 << str << endl;
    }
    f1.clear();
    f1.seekg(0);
    while (getline(f1, str)) {
        f2 << str << endl;
    }
    f1.close();
    f2.close();
}
```